# Finding a specific value and returning column headers in Excel

Tags: excel, header, lookup, textjoin

I want to find all the headers if the row contains "No data". The data sample is below:
[image]

In F2, I want to get "England, India". F3 should be "France, Germany, US, India".

How can I do this in Excel 2013? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:E2="No data",$A$1:$E$1,""))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then put this code in a module attached to the workbook:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Then use the TEXTJOIN() formula as described above.

Answer (score 0):

A "simple" solution using the "IF" function can solve it. Insert the following formula in F2 and drag the formula down to all the rows it's needed:

```
=if(A2<>"";if(isnumber(A2);"";$A$1&", ");"")&if(B2<>"";if(isnumber(B2);"";$B$1&", ");"")&if(C2<>"";if(isnumber(C2);"";$C$1&", ");"")&if(D2<>"";if(isnumber(D2);"";$D$1&", ");"")&if(E2<>"";if(isnumber(E2);"";$E$1&", ");"")
```

In plain text, if it's easier to copy:
=if(A2<>"";if(isnumber(A2);"";$A$1&", ");"")&if(B2<>"";if(isnumber(B2);"";$B$1&", ");"")&if(C2<>"";if(isnumber(C2);"";$C$1&", ");"")&if(D2<>"";if(isnumber(D2);"";$D$1&", ");"")&if(E2<>"";if(isnumber(E2);"";$E$1&", ");"")

Please note that I have used "isnumber" to identify if there is no data. This means that all data that you insert must be in numbers for the formula to work.

If, at some point in time, you need to expand the formula, you can just add this to the end of the current formula, replacing the bold X's with the column letter at hand (add from row 2 and drag it down):

&if(**X**2<>"";if(isnumber(**X**2);"";$**X**$1&", ");"")